# how to avoid type error in python

Tags: python, file

I wanted to read an integer value from a text file and wanted to give that same value to  `time.sleep()`. But I am getting:

```
Type Error: a float is required
```

How can I avoid this?

```
  if os.path.exists('save.txt'):

    f=open("save.txt","r")
    d=f.read()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    count=5
    while (count):
      f=open ("test1.txt", "rb")
      l = f.read(1024)

      s.sendto(l,("10.0.0.1",9999))
      count=count-1
      time.sleep(d)
```

> this my code

Comment: Please show us your code; *what line* is throwing the `TypeError`? Have you tried turning that argument into a float by using `float()` yet?

Comment: if it's an integer, why not cast it?
`time.sleep(float(integer_value))`

Comment: "How can I avoid this?" - You can avoid this by providing float in place of non float wherever it expects it.

Comment: Python is capable of implicit conversion of integer to float. Strings are the tricky one

Comment: You are reading value from a text file. Your data that had read from text file may contain spaces etc. try `float(d.strip())`

Comment: when i convert as time.sleep(float(d)) it is showing "could not convert string to float"

Comment: @FallenAngel, *float* and *int* ignore spaces, so strip is redundant

Comment: Can you show us your code? You are doing something wrong. Also what is your python version?

Comment: @neethuK, print value of *d*. Obviously, it is not what you expect it to be

Comment: yup i printed that value it is the same one stored in that file..

Comment: if os.path.exists('save.txt'):  
      f=open("save.txt","r")
      d=f.read()
      .........
      while (count):
        f=open ("test1.txt", "rb")
        l = f.read(1024)

        s.sendto(l,("10.0.0.1",9999))
        count=count-1
        time.sleep(float(d))

Comment: If you read the contents of a file and try to convert it to `float`, then you will get `ValueError: could not convert xxx to float` at worst. You are talking about `TypeError`

Comment: @neethuK Please edit your question and add your code there with indentation...

Comment: @neethuK, exactly - method *read* returns string, you have to convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn it into a float using `float()`.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> float(a)
10.0
```

This will also work on strings (which is usually what user input or file input is taken in as):

```
>>> float('10')
10.0
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that no conversion was done at all - the value was transferred "as is" - which is, naturally, *str*

Comment: This will work as well when a is a string - which it will be if read from a text file.  `float("1")` will return `1.0`.

Comment: @volcano As @neil said and I just checked myself right now, `float` will work on strings as well.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, sleep will not work with strings

Comment: @volcano for sure, but I'm talking about the conversion :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, you missed the whole point. Let me explain from beginning to the end. If OP has provided integer argument, *sleep* would have worked. Obviously, **raw** value from the file read was used, which is string. Your answer supposed conversion from *int* to *float*.